# transition animations for subviews in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, transition

I've been researching this for ages and cannot find any answers on here or online that addresses how to create custom transitions for when a subview appears/disappears.

What I'm trying to do...  I have a badge view `TestBadgeView` and a `TestBadgeInsideHStackView`, which as the name suggests, is just a HStack with an embedded `TestBadgeView`.  On the preview screen, using `TestTransitionView`, I have a textfield that allows updating of the text that is displayed inside the badge.  The badge at the middle of the screen is always visible but can be hidden/made visible using the Show/Hide Me button. That transition uses a scale animation by calling `.transition(.scale)` modifier.  For the badge at the top right of the screen (to the right of the text badge--->, which is inside the `TestBadgeInsideHStackView`, I'm trying to get that badge to only display when the user types in `hello world` into the text field.  That works but I can't get the transition animation to work.  This is a simplified version of my code but I'm ultimately trying to get the parent view to pass data down to a subview which then, based on the logic is either visible or not, but that visibility should be animated with a transition.  Any ideas?

You should be able to cut and paste the code below to test/trial.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestTransitionView: View {
    
    @State var showView: Bool = true
    @State var text: String = "hello"
    
    var body: some View {
        
            VStack {
                               
                TextField("textfield", text: $text)
                    .padding()
                    .border(.gray)
                    .padding()
                
                TestBadgeInsideHStackView(shouldShowBadge: text == "hello world") {
                    Text(text.uppercased())
                }
                
                HStack {
    
                    if showView {
                        Text(text.uppercased())
                            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                            .padding(.vertical, 7)
                            .background(Rectangle()
                                .fill(.gray).opacity(0.1)
                                .cornerRadius(6)
                            )
                            .font(.caption)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .transition(.scale)
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: 100)
                .padding()
                
                Spacer()
                Button("Show/Hide Me") {
                    withAnimation {
                        showView.toggle()
                    }
                }.padding(50)
            }
    }
}


struct TestBadgeInsideHStackView<Content: View> : View {
    let content: Content
    private var shouldShowBadge: Bool
    
    init(shouldShowBadge: Bool, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
        self.shouldShowBadge = shouldShowBadge
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("badge ---> ")
            Spacer()
            if shouldShowBadge {
                TestBadgeView {
                    content
                }
                .transition(.scale)
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 100)
        .padding()
    }
}


struct TestBadgeView<Content: View>: View {
    let content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
        
    var body: some View {
        content
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            .padding(.vertical, 7)
            .background(Rectangle()
                .fill(.gray).opacity(0.1)
                .cornerRadius(6)
            )
            .font(.caption)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .transition(.scale)
    }
}



#Preview {
    TestTransitionView()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The flag `showView` is being toggled `withAnimation`, but changes to the text field are not associated with any form of animation. This is why the transition is not animated when a change is triggered due to the text being edited.

Here are two ways to fix:

1. Add `.animation()` to the binding passed to the `TextField`:

```swift
TextField("textfield", text: $text.animation())
```

2. Or, add an `.animation` modifier to the `HStack` in `TestBadgeInsideHStackView`:

```swift
// TestBadgeInsideHStackView

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        // content as before
    }
    .animation(.easeInOut, value: shouldShowBadge) // <- ADDED
    // other modifiers as before
}
```

BTW, I would suggest defining both the properties in `TestBadgeInsideHStackView` using `private let`:

```swift
private let content: Content
private let shouldShowBadge: Bool
```

Comment: Answer updated with another possible solution